# log4j2 level inheritance not working

Tags: log4j2

```
<Loggers>
        <Logger name="X.Y.Z">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="X.Y">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="X">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="trace" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
</Loggers>
```

This is my log4j.xml file.

The below details are what I am getting if I use Configuration object in Java code.

```
X.Y.Z --- ERROR ----Parent : X.Y
X.Y   --- ERROR ----Parent : X
X     --- ERROR ----Parent : root
root  --- TRACE ----Parent : null
```

The above details tell us the proper Parent name but it's not inheriting levels from parent logger "root".

Answer (score 1):

It is more common to use the `additivity="false"` attribute on the named `Logger`s, instead of on the `Root` logger.

The final part of your question is unclear to me. What do you mean exactly by "... if I use Configuration object..."? Are you configuring log4j2 with Java source code in addition to the log4j2.xml configuration file? Or are you simply calling `Logger.trace`? Can you show the source code?

Also, can you show your *complete* log4j2.xml configuration?

When you say "The below details are what I am getting...", do you mean that this is the output generated by Log4j on the console?

Comment: Quote: 'The root logger does not support the additivity attribute since it has no parent.'. Reference: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Appenders

Answer (score 1):

In the docs it says that you can't put the `additivity` attribute on the Root logger because it doesn't make sense. There is no logger above it to add to.

Additivity basically means "pass on log entries to the parent logger in the hierarchy"

It doesn't inherit levels from the parent. A log entry has a level. Whether it is printed depends on whether there is a logger to catch such an entry (one that accepts that level).

So X.Y.Z will pass logs to X.Y unless `additivity=false` is set on the X.Y.Z logger config. And so on